# How to test laravel 5.2 projects with Travis CI

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, travis-ci

I have made a project in Laravel 5.2 and its source code is deployed at github [here](https://github.com/theopenblog/theopenblog). I'm having trouble testing the project with PHPUnit and integrating with Travis-CI.

This is my Travis-CI config file:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6

before_script:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - mysql -e 'create database homestead_test;'
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This is my PHPUnit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

The other files can be seen in my repository. Please comment below if you need any clarifications.

My travis Build can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/TheOpenBlog/TheOpenBlog).

This is the error I'm getting in Travis build:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/travis/build/TheOpenBlog/TheOpenBlog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/travis/build/TheOpenBlog/TheOpenBlog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The database I created was wrong.

The correct .travis.yml file is

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6

before_script:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - mysql -e 'create database TheOpenBlog_tests;'
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

corrected .env.travis file

```
APP_ENV=TheOpenBlog_testing
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_CONNECTION=TheOpenBlog_testing
DB_DATABASE=TheOpenBlog_tests
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

and finally add this

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="TheOpenBlog_testing"/>
```

and remove this

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="TheOpenBlog_testing"/>
```